# how to update from and date(1970-01-01)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is a oscommerce code. I have used bootstrap date picker. But this date picker is can work but. I have selected begin date and end date and mode also have selected only its working. other wise its display a default date 1970/01/01.

```
<tr>
    <td width="100%" style="padding: 10px">
        <b><?php  echo TEXT_BEGINDATE;?></b>
        (yyyy-mm-dd):
        <input name="startdate" id="start_date" type="text" value="<? 

            if(date("Y-m-d",$report->begindate)==1970-01-01) { 
                echo date("Y-m-d",$report->begindate/*, $report->begindate*/);
            } else {
                echo date("Y-m-d",$report->begindate/*, $report->begindate*/);}
        ?>" />


        <b><?php  echo TEXT_ENDDATE;?></b>
        (yyyy-mm-dd):
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="enddate" id="end_date" type="text"
            value="<?echo date("Y-m-d",$report->enddate/*, $report->enddate*/); ?>" />

<script>
$(function(){
   $('#start_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
   $('#end_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
</script>
```

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: I love this piece of code: `if(date("Y-m-d",$report->begindate)==1970-01-01)`

Comment: You can change it to `if(date("Y-m-d",$report->begindate)==1968)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The code as it is will not work, because of the syntax of the comparison (or rather it will not work as expected - see my previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

PHP date function returns a formatted date based on two parameters:

- First one is the display format
- Second one (optional) is a timestamp

If the second parameter is lower than the one corresponding to 01/01/1970, the date returned by dat() will still be 01/01/1970.

**From the php doc**:
*The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer). However, **before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038** on some systems (e.g. Windows).*

Maybe your variable $report->begindate doesn't contain the appropriate data

Comment: I can't believe you actually understood what the OP was asking.  I still can't.

Comment: You seem to have misinterpreted my comment.  What I meant to say is that I don't think your answer has anything to do with the question.

Comment: You're right, i misunterstood your comment. Here's what I understood about the question (as far as "But this date picker is can work but. I have selected begin date and end date and mode also have selected only its working" can be considered as an understandable sentence): The date displayed is always 01/01/1970, that's why I oriented him on a bad formatted timestamp